# Running a specific provision block with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I'm wanting to run a separate provisioning block in my Vagrant file on the newly provisioned server. At present when I run this from my CI server

```
vagrant up
```

the following blocks are executed successfully

```
config.vm.provider :linode do |provider, override|   
    #creates a new instance etc .. the following block runs on this instance
end
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.provisioning_path = "/tmp/deploy"
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks"]
    chef.add_recipe = "mydeployagent" 
end
```

now i want to run a separate provisioner afterwards. (a separate task in CI server) i.e.

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.provisioning_path = "/tmp/deploy"
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks"]
    chef.add_recipe = "mydeploydatabaseagent" 
end
```

I'm trying to figure out what I need to

1. run vagrant up so that it only executes the 1st provision block
2. run vagrant so that it will only run the 2nd provisioner block on the instance that was created in 1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do. Are you spinning up more than one VM? If that is the case how the provisioners work and execution order is described in the documentation: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/index.html

Comment: RTM: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Vagrant docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html).

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # ... other configuration

  config.vm.provision "bootstrap", type: "shell" do |s|
    s.inline = "echo hello"
  end
end
```

> The --provision-with flag can be used if you only want to run a
>   specific provisioner if you have multiple provisioners specified. For
>   example, if you have a shell and Puppet provisioner and only want to
>   run the shell one, you can do vagrant provision --provision-with
>   shell. The arguments to --provision-with can be the provisioner type
>   (such as "shell") or the provisioner name (such as "bootstrap" from
>   above).

Answer (score 0):

Chef is about managing a desired state so you should be wanting it to ensure your two recipes are run at each time (and they should be idempotent).

I don't know any way to tell vagrant to use twice the same provisoner with different parameters (I can only think about ugly hacks in the vagrant file for that)

If the second recipe depends on the first one to have been executed then you may add a guard to skip this second recipe until the first one has run.

With chef-solo you may do something like this:

- mydeployagent/recipes/default.rb

```rb
[...Whatever your recipe has to do (agent install, configuration, etc...]

# On a particular resource on your first recipe, 
# trigger a notification to make a file which will be used as a guard for second recipe
remote_file "/opt/target/mydeplaoyagent" do
  source [.. your source..]
  notifies :create,"file[/opt/mydeployagent.initialized]"
end

file "/opt/mydeployagent.initialized" do
 action :nothing
end
```

- mydeploydatabaseagent/recipes/default.rb

```rb
#start the recipe by a guard to avoid doing anythng if first recipe has not been run
return unless ::File::exists?("/opt/mydeployagent.initialized")

[... your second recipe code here ...]
```

And in your vagrant file your can add the two recipes to your provisioner like:

```rb
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.provisioning_path = "/tmp/deploy"
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks"]
    chef.add_recipe = "mydeployagent" 
    chef.add_recipe = "mydeploydatabaseagent"
end
```

Obviously the guard can be used on top of the first recipe too if it is not idempotent, but I highly encourage to rethink it to be able to run multiples times, you'll be happy to have it running when you'll have a configuration change to propagate in a file managed by this recipe (and trust me, you will have an update like this to manage one day).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, in this case the answer below using a named provisioner got me across the line